# Erro na query MYSQL

Tags: mysql, query

Tenho a seguinte query

```
select DISTINCT(p.id),g.id, p.slug, p.nome
from game g
join game_plataforma gp on g.id=gp.id_game
join plataformas p on gp.id_plataforma=p.id
group by g.id,p.id,p.slug, p.nome
order by g.id DESC
limit 5;
```

Ela retorna isso aqui
[image: query]

Já tentei de várias formas mas não acho o erro.

Quero listar as plataformas em ordem decrescente pela data de postagem dos jogos. Já quase faz isso mas quero agrupar ou no caso mostrar diferente, então minha lista deveria ser

```
xbox
play4
nintendo3ds
```

e só mostraria esses 3

---

alterei para

```
    select DISTINCT(p.id), p.slug, p.nome
from game g
join game_plataforma gp on g.id=gp.id_game
join plataformas p on gp.id_plataforma=p.id
group by p.nome
order by g.id DESC
limit 5
```

e deu este erro

```
#1055 - Expression #1 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column 'desapego.p.id' which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e6520/4/0 no fidle funciona

Comment: **`group by g.id,p.id,p.slug, p.nome`**? Por quê?

Comment: Faça o GROUP só por nome, e ordene por MIN( campodadata ) se for pela postagem mais antiga, ou MAX( campodadata ) se for pela postagem mais nova. - Essa query sua parece meio "enrolada" pro objetivo. Jogue alguns dados de exemplo no http://SQLFiddle.com com a estrutura real da tabela e ítens suficientes para teste, que podemos resolver mais rapidamente.

Comment: vou por la pera ai

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e6520/4/0 no fiddle funcionou assim no meu mysql deu este erro que postei acima

Comment: @JasarOrion precisa ver se tem alguma diferença de engine ou versão. E veja se dá pra tirar o distinct também. A lógica é mais ou menos o que eu comentei, mas as especificidades vc precisa testar aí, é complicado saber o que está acontecendo (ainda mais que no fiddle funcionou).

Comment: estou usando o mysql 5.7